# Results set returns empty when records exist. Statement works when executed in console, not in code. Why?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to obtain records from my MySQL database that I am not hosting. My code will not produce any results or throw any errors. I am just getting an empty results set even though there are definitely records that exist in the database. In fact, when I write my statement in console, it returns the data. I'm not sure why it isn't working in the code.

What I've tried:

I tested my SQL query statement in console to double check it is correct. The statement works in console, so I don't think this is it.

My SQL connection should be working because I use the same connection method in another part of the code where I am inserting records into the database and it works there. I do close the connection I create there as soon as the method I am getting results from is complete to avoid concurrent connections.

I tried stopping the console connection to make sure the issue wasn't from concurrent connections. I don't think it is, because I completely deleted the data source out of my console and I was still running into the issue. Plus, even when the database exists in my console, I can still add records without running into any issues.

For more info, I am coding this on Intellij Idea. My console is also Intellij's database console. The database is a MySQL database that I do not host on my machine.

OLD CODE, NEW CODE HAS BEEN UPDATED PER COMMENTS (ISSUE STILL ONGOING)

```
public ObservableList loadUsers(){
        Connection conn;
        PreparedStatement stmt;
        ResultSet rs;
        //userList is a global var in this class declared at the top
        userList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        try {
            conn = Model.SQL_Connection.connect();
            System.out.println(conn);
            String resultString = "select userID, userName, lastUpdate, lastUpdatedBy from user";
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(resultString);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            //used this to check size of resultset
            //it always returns 0
            System.out.println(rs.getFetchSize());
            //for each row
            while(rs.next()){
                //Iterate Row
                ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                //for each column
                for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                    row.add(rs.getString(i));
                }
                userList.add(row);
            }
            conn.close();

         } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
        //convert results if needed
        //put results into table
        return userList;
    }
```

NEW CODE:

```
public ObservableList loadUsers(){
    //call result set
    Connection conn;
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    userList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        conn = Model.SQL_Connection.connect();
        System.out.println(conn);
        String resultString = "select userID, userName, lastUpdate, lastUpdatedBy from user";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(resultString);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        //for each row
        while(rs.next()){
            //Iterate Row
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            //for each column
            for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            userList.add(row);
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //convert results if needed
    //put results into table
    return userList;
}
```

Results from code above are that the connection was successful, not throwing any errors, and that the rs.getFetchSize() is 0. I think this is the right method to use to test but this is my first SQL project so I could be wrong.

If someone knows what I could do to return actual results, I would greatly appreciate it. I've spent quite a few hours looking around, but maybe it's something simple that someone with more experience will be able to spot. I will follow up here if I find a solution.

Comment: what about strict follow "close resultset then close statement then close connection" policy? You seems only close connection.

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the same database. Are you sure you committed the data? Also, please read the JDBC API documentation, `fetchSize` doesn't do what you think it does. It _"[g]ives the JDBC driver a hint as to the number of rows that should be fetched from the database when more rows are needed for this ResultSet object."_ So it isn't the number of rows in a result set.

Comment: @yuanqingfei Thank you for pointing this out to me, I was wondering about it but I wasn't sure because the examples I was viewing didn't include it. thanks for showing me best practice, I will do this going forward. Additionally code has been updated, but I'm still seeing the same result.

Comment: ```rs.refreshRow();```
Try this.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for your comment, I am connecting to the same database. In regards to the getFetchSize, thank you for pointing this out. I instead implemented a println inside the while loop and it worked! It's printing 3 times for three records. That means something about the way I'm reading the information is wrong. Thanks for helping me narrow it down.